# Upload Javascript Date to Firestore using Seconds/Nanoseconds

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, date-conversion

I'm trying to convert dates in the format of MM/DD/YYYY to the following format of seconds/nanoseconds. The question I have is why is my time out of the bounds? Am I supposed to remove zeros?:

**Format:**

```
"license_expiration_date": {
  "_seconds": 1560988800000,
  "_nanoseconds": 0
 }
```

**Code to Convert:**

```
let date = new Date('06/20/2019');

let time = date.getTime();

console.log(time);
```

**Output:**

```
1560988800000
```

**Error:**

```
status: false,
  message: 'Value for argument "seconds" must be within [-62135596800, 253402300799] inclusive, but was: 1587340800000'
```

Comment: The value you're assigning to *seconds* appears to be milliseconds. Try dividing by 1000 and removing the decimal part.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help! If you want to add it as an answer, I'll vote it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the comment from RobG as a community wiki answer:

The value you're assigning to seconds appears to be milliseconds. Try dividing by 1000 and removing the decimal part.